# Convert Dapper raw SQL Result to Nested JSON Array

Tags: json, vue.js, dapper, asp.net-core-5.0

I have developed a web api in .Net Core 5 which uses dapper to run a tabled valued function and return the SQL results. These results are then used to fill various select boxes on the front end in VueJS. However, when I began to build out my front end more I realized my JSON arrays could be nested to really help reduce the number of requests I make to the server as my select boxes are dependent. For instance, one select box includes states and then next select box relates to the cities in those states. Adjusting the tabled value function to return a single table was easy by adding a innerjoin between my state table in the database and the cities table. The joining key was a field called STATE_ID. Therefore I just have multiple rows due to multiple cities per state. So now what I am trying to figure out is how to take this result in my web api and my table valued function result without the use of models into a nested json array such that my results are as follows:

```
[{state: 'Maryland', cities :[{city: 'Baltimore'}, {city: 'Harford County'}]} , 
{state: 'Pennsylvania', cities :[{city: 'York'}, {city: 'Fawn Grove'}]}]
```

Table valued function result from A2Q00001_StateInfo(USERNUMBER):

```
|      State_ID       |     State_Name   |      City_Name      |  
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          1          |      Maryland    |    Baltimore        |
|          1          |      Maryland    | Harford County      |
|          2          |  Pennsylvania    |    York             |
|          2          |  Pennsylvania    | Fawn Grove          |
```

My controller is as follows:

```
        public ActionResult StateAndCities([FromQuery] String USERNUMBER)
        {
 
            //We have parameters here just in case we want to use them
            IEnumerable queryResult;
            String query = "select * from dbo.A2Q00001_StateInfo(@USERNUMBER);";

            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                queryResult = connection.Query(query, new { USERNUMBER = USERNUMBER });
            }

            return Ok(queryResult);

        }
```

All of the tutorials I have seen online use models to create the nested JSON object and return it however I am not sure how to create the nested object using the serialization in the Ok() function in asp.net core. Is this even posssible or do I need to perform operations on the queryResult from the dapper query? Any point in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice: split this into steps. I'm guessing your `A2Q00001_StateInfo` UDF here returns a `State` and `City` column (edit: I was close, it was `State_Name`, via the edit), among other things. So first step: let's just read that:

```cs
class SomeType
{
    public string State_Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
//...
var queryResult = connection.Query<SomeType>(
    "select State_Name, City from dbo.A2Q00001_StateInfo(@USERNUMBER);",
    new { USERNUMBER }).AsList();
```

This gets our data from the database into local memory. Note that I filtered out irrelevant columns to reduce overheads.

Now, the *next* step is to structure that data - it looks like you want to aggregate by state, and create an array of the cities in each; so: let's do that:

```cs
var structured =
    from grp in queryResult.GroupBy(x => x.State_Name)
    select new
    {
        state = grp.Key,
        cities = grp.Select(row => new { city = row.City }).ToArray()
    };
```

This gives us a projection (using anonymous types) that does the restructuring we want. Finally, we need to convert it to JSON; this *might* be as simple as:

```cs
return Ok(structured);
```

Or you might need to use the `Json`/`JsonResult` APIs directly. However, now that the data is structured: any JSON serializer should know what we want to do here.

---

Note: you probably *can* rewrite all this into a single expression, but: *don't do that*; you're not trying to impress the compiler - it won't care either way. Make the code clear and obvious for the next person who is going to need to touch it (which might well be you).

Comment: I have added what the table looks like above in the original question to provide better context. By moving the table into local memory looks similar to using Models . If that is the case is it possible to do without shifting to local memory and using models and using my original table result?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 you're going to have to move relational data to local memory either way, unless you want to fight `FOR JSON` at the database server, which I **do not recommend**. As for "using models" - um, yes? that's pretty normal and expected - although arguably this is a very dumb DTO/POCO here, so calling it a "model" might be overkill. I take it that you preferred the `dynamic` API? well, you *can* do that with everything I wrote above, but I strongly advise against it (and for context: I wrote Dapper). You could also use a value-tuple, i.e. `.Query<(string State, string City)>(....)`

Comment: Thanks for the response. So we have a SQL guy who does these functions for us on the database server and gets the results we want so we can focus on other stuff and keep seperate from our web api code. Is the modifications you do to the queryResult object using LINQ (I am still learning asp.net core so forgive me if that is a dumb question)? Also , what is the issues using For JSON if it were to remove any LINQ requirements on my end and to just use the results from the db server?

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 remember that your database server is your most limited resource; also remember that JSON data is going to be larger bandwidth. If you don't care about those things, and can figure out how to do it with `FOR JSON`: have fun with that. I wouldn't touch it with a long pole

Comment: lol. I get the point. This is a locally hosted database server and locally hosted IIS server with maybe 20 users max. The FOR JSON might be easier to implement so would you mind showing in your solution how you would create the results from that given I have the table now added to the question? Also I will mark your solution as the correct one regardless since your LINQ solution is probably the best route regardless. Thanks so much because your solution was laid out very clearly.

Comment: @Bradyboyy88 if you can get `FOR JSON` working, then I *guess* that `var json 
= QuerySingle<string>("your sql here", new { USERNUMBER });` would get the data, followed by `return Content(json, "application/json");`